# Signal Amazon EC2 from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am looking to run C++ code on an Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu. I need to signal the C++ app when data in an S3 database is updated. What is the best way of doing this. The C++ app would then read the relevant data from S3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the supported S3 event types [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html).

If one ore more of those event types will accomplish what you need, then you can have your application subscribe to an SNS Topic in order to get notifications when those events occur.